# Radiation shield with moving electrons - where would this idea fail?

Tags: nuclear-engineering

Disclaimer: I'm a total layman, please go easy on me. :)

On some Youtube video some time ago (yes, sounds promising, but it was a quality video, I swear!) I saw some nuclear physicist talking about nuclear power generators and why there will never be "portable nuclear <s>batteries</s> reactors". It all came down to having a radiation shield thick enough. The guy said - stray <s>neutrons</s> gamma rays are stopped by electrons, so you need a lot of electrons around the nuclear core. This translates to simply a lot of mass, aka meters thick concrete.

And I got wondering - would it be possible to use less mass if it was moving? A small amount of electrons, yet moving quickly (a significant fraction of lightspeed) in circles around the nuclear core could shield just as well as a much thicker layer of static electrons, no? Meaning that for each <s>neutron</s> gamma ray trying to cross the barrier the chance of hitting an electron would be around the same.

Now, I don't suppose I'm the first one with the idea, so I guess it's not really feasible, but I wonder where it falls apart? Would the energy requirements for such an "active shield" be too large? Are the <s>neutrons</s> gamma rays moving too fast for this to work? Would there be even worse side effects?

Comment: Portable nuclear batteries have been around for decades. They were even used in pacemakers in the 1970s. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betavoltaic_device

Comment: @PM2Ring - Sorry, I meant "portable nuclear reactor".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Electrons are very unsuitable for stopping neutrons because the neutron's mass is 2000 times higher than that of the electron. Ever tried to stop a train by staying on the rails? That is what it feels like for an electron to try to stop a neutron.

What you need to stop a neutron is something that is about as heavy as the neutron itself, that is preferably a proton/hydrogen (or water to be more practical).

Anything much heavier than the neutron will most probably just reflect the neutron. Anything much lighter will just get rolled over.

When it comes to gamma ray, you do indeed need a high density of charges to shield them, because gamma photons are either absorbed, scattered or generate electron-positron pairs, each of which requires at least weakly bound electrons. Since lead is a dense material, it means that it also has a high density of protons per volume (nuclear neutrons also contribute to the mass, but the number of protons and neutrons per nucleus are more or less correlated for stable nuclei), which in turn means it has many electrons per volume.

If you want to emulate the high density of electrons in lead, you would have to keep them in a small volume by some force, which is difficult because like charges repel. So there is hardly any better way to concentrate electrons than by binding them to heavy nuclei.

BTW, as mentioned in the comments, a "nuclear battery" is the term for something that uses natural decay for producing (small amounts) of energy, like in pacemakers or satellites. It seems like you actually mean portable "nuclear reactors", to which the mentioned rules with respect to shielding apply.

Comment: Hmm... perhaps then it was some other radiation he was talking about? Gamma rays maybe? What was the dangerous part in radiation? Gamma rays or neutrons or something else?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I think I mixed up neutrons and gamma rays! Correcting the question.

Comment: Yes, portable nuclear reactors.  The video was about nuclear-powered cars and the nuclear batteries would not be powerful enough for that.

Comment: Still, what about the idea of moving few electrons around quickly? The density is smaller, but the chance of hitting one is larger.

Comment: "The density is smaller, but the chance of hitting one is larger." - sorry, but no. It would only apply if gamma rays were something moving very slowly in a fast moving medium of electrons. It is the opposite: they are moving with a speed of light, and electrons are nowhere near that (especially if you do not intend to build a portable accelerator as well, but even then).